# What's the meaning of 〜までに here?

Tags: grammar

I found a tweet about the Taiwanese snack known as 炸鶏排. The tweet reads:

> 日本でも食べられるようになったのにイマイチ流行ってないので試しに買ってみたら味はスゴくいい。Lチキとかの億倍美味い。ただただ致命的なまでにデカすぎた

which I can pretty easily translate to:

> Even though we can get this in Japan now, it's not that popular so I decided to try it. It tastes pretty darn good. It's like a million times better than Lawson fried chicken. The only thing is that it's so big it'll kill you.

But I don't remember seeing 〜までに in this capacity before. To me, usually までに indicates a date by which something has to be done. What does it mean in this context, then?

Comment: Literally "to the point where it is critical", but simply "critically". (Of course 致命的 used like this does not mean it's really lethal.)